# Efficient Bitmaps

Tags: android, optimization, bitmap

Recently, while trying to load a image in imageView I ran into "Out of Heap Memory" error. So I looked on internet and found the way to optimise the images.

I am looking forward to finding the best way to optimise a bitmap.

Currently, I have an ImageView which has 200dp as hight and "match_parent" for width. Basically it fills the screen horizontally and takes 200dp vertically.

I am trying to achieve something like in this image.

[image: ACHIEVEMENT]

Here is my master plan to do so.

1) Create a layout for 1 row (ImageView, TextView, Black Translucent bar behind text)

2) Use RecyclerView and inflate the data

Currently I am stuck on Step 1 (not satisfied with code).

What I did is create an XML layout for the row.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_adventure_fragment"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_adventure_home_screen_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/textview_background_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView_adventure_name_home_screen_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="Demo Text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'll adjust TextView as per Typography guidelines later.

Ok, so basically ImageView is 200dp tall.
To compress my images I used the guide at Android training page which uses inSampleSize and loads image in an AsyncTask.

To calculate the required height I used something I am not sure if it is correct way or not. Since I care to compress image only for height I passed only height to calculate inSampleSize.

```
    DisplayMetrics disp = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int density = disp.densityDpi;
    width = disp.widthPixels;
    height = (int)((float)(200.0/160.0) * (float)density);

    Bitmap b =decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.shake,height);
    loadBitmap(R.drawable.shake,iV);
```

Finally I extracted thumbnail from the final bitmap for the required width and height to show user an image which fills the imageView instead of being just in the centre with margins.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,width,height));
```

Full code can be found here : http://pastebin.com/mhKi1sKd

What is the best way to optimise the imageView so that in case multiple images are shown in a RecyclerView, Heap memory does not get full and also if there are unnecessary codes in my program that simply take up processing and valuable time?

This is what I have achieved till now.

[image: Achieved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

> Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled
>   automatically by Picasso:
>
> ```
> Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
> Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
> Automatic memory and disk caching.
> ```